# kivy ios launch image

Tags: ios, kivy, launch

I've created an app for ios using kivy. I was able to add a launch image, but when the app starts the launch image appears for one second, then the screen becomes blank for a couple of more seconds and then the app starts. Is there any way to keep the launch image until the app starts? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Babak

Comment: how have you added a launch image exactly? I added one via the buildozer.spec file and it stays as long as the default kivy splash stayed on screen, that is to say without any gap between it disappearing and the app starting. What is the format of the image that you added?

Comment: I used buildozer to build the android version and everything works well on android now. Did you use buildozer to build for ios? If so, could you please point me to any instructions?

Thanks Babak

Comment: no only for android. however, you've probably seen this page, but look here for info on ios http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html

Answer (score 2):

Kivy provides a way fix for iOS apps [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-ios.html#customize):

*Launch Images are supported. By default, XCode want you to build an Image Sets. This is your responsability to fill all the images needed for the Sets, depending of your target. However, Kivy use SDL, and as soon as the application starts the SDL main, the launch image will disapear. To prevent that, you need to have 2 files named Default.png and Default-Landscape.png, and put them in the Resources folder in Xcode (not in your application folder)*